# Why do fats have an even number of carbon atoms in their fatty acids?

Tags: organic-chemistry

Can **betaoxidation** and **unsaturated** fats in any way be used in explaining why fatty acids in most cases have an even amount of carbon atoms?

Comment: Oxidation is the reverse of what you need. Fats are not built by oxidation. As for the unsaturated fats, I don't think they are related to this question.

Comment: @IvanNeretin the exact question is: "Explain in your own words why most fats have an even amount of carbon atoms in their fatty acids. You can assume that it involves betaoxidation and unsaturated fats."                     I cannot either make sense of it.

Comment: All right, beta oxidation might make sense if we assume that the fats are built by the same process in reverse, that is, by adding C2 fragments. (I don't remember if that's true, but sounds plausible.) Unsaturated fats still puzzle me.

Comment: It says "it involves betaoxidation", so why don't you add what you know about that to your question. I know an answer to the exact question, but don't know how to explain it in your own words.

Comment: @KarstenTheis how would you have answered the question?

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/64348/do-unsaturated-fatty-acids-with-an-odd-number-of-carbons-exist